# Lost my vacuum release plug on my 5 gallon water carrier

Tags: camping

Does anyone know I can replace the tiny white plastic vacuum release plug on my Coleman 5 gallon plastic water carrier?   I lost it camping.

Comment: Coleman supply an extensive set of spares through stockists around the world.

Comment: In what way is this "price-shopping"? And if it's "off-topic" why are you answering it?